# docker.iso 100% disk usage

Tags: windows, docker

I designed a program to classify images. Main task is to load the image, extract mean gray level, and go to the next image. I then use the gray levels to train a machine learning algorithm.
My issue is that I have to make this work on a windows 10 Pro environment.
Si I thought docker would be a nice and easy way to go : I put everything into a container, mount the volumes containing the images and it's over.

My exact process :

1. build image
2. run image :

> docker run  -v c:/images:/images  -v c:/images2:/images2 -v
>   c:/images3:/images3 --name mycontainer --rm -p 8000:8000 myimage

3. enter docker :

> docker exec -it mycontainer bash

4. run my script :

> python train.py

The code runs for a while (12h or so), and at some point the disk usage starts to increase (I'm supposed to read one image every second or so, so disk usage should be minimal) up to 500Mb/s (it takes a few hours(3h) of steady increase between normal usage and 400Mb/s), which is the disk limit. At that point my code is still running, but so slow it's not useful anymore.

If I check what process is taking all disk resources, I have 3 main :

- docker.iso (200Mb/s)
- docker-desktop.iso (150 Mb/s)
- dockerDesktop.vhdx    (75Mb/s)

Docker stats :
Here are the results of the docker stats command:

After 12h, working normally :

```
CONTAINER ID        NAME                    CPU %               MEM USAGE / LIMIT     MEM %               NET I/O             BLOCK I/O           PIDS
870335b0443d        classification_huiles   253.01%             360.2MiB / 3.846GiB   9.15%               4.46kB / 0B         195MB / 73.7kB      12
```

At the end :

```
CONTAINER ID        NAME                    CPU %               MEM USAGE / LIMIT     MEM %               NET I/O             BLOCK I/O           PIDS
870335b0443d        classification_huiles   251.10%             360.7MiB / 3.846GiB   9.16%               4.67kB / 0B         **56.4GB** / 73.7kB     12
```

As you can see, BLOCK I/O is increasing very fast, and mem_usage and MEM % are still low

I've tried :

- Increasing memory/CPU of docker
- Updating everything I can on windows : I'm now up to date, with docker 2.2.0.0
- Checking for memory leak in my code : my code runs fine without docker on windows
- Restart everything and try again : **it takes about the same time to fail.**

I don't understand why docker would use so much the disk, and what I could do to fix this. Any advice are much appreciated.

EDIT : I'm running image continuumio/anaconda3:2019.10

Comment: I haven't found the full answer to this, but there is little information about this issue, so I'm adding this comment if you encounter the same issue. There is apparently an issue in shared drive with Docker on Windows. When the container tries to read some resources on the shared drive, for some reason it can't and get stuck using more an more disk bandwidth. **Doing a factory reset of docker seems to fix the issue.** Given the unstable nature of this issue, I decided to move away from docker on windows.